# Way to set conflict domain on INV org level for Concurrent prog in Oracle Apps

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, erp, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I want to set conflict domain(incompatibility) on INV org level for Concurrent prog in Oracle Apps.
Suppose we have three orgs A,B,C my concurrent prog name is xyz

xyz should run for all three orgs at a time but not for A and A or B and B or C and C

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as per Oracle AOL document.

Conflict Domains
In Oracle Applications, data is stored in database tables that belong to a particular application. Each table may also contain information used to determine what conditions need to be met to access the individual records. These conditions may consist of one or more of the following data groupings:

- SOB - based on the profile option
- GL_SET_OF_BOOKS Multiple installations (referred to as MSOB) Multiple Operating units
  (determined by profile option MO_OPERATING_UNIT) (referred as MULTIORG).
- Multiple Orgs (determined by profile option INV_ORGANIZATION_ID, Used by Manufacturing Applications)
- HR may use business group as a conflict resolution domain FA may use FA book
- etc...

All programs are assigned a conflict domain when they are submitted. If a domain is defined as part of a parameter the concurrent manager will use it to resolve incompatibilities. If the domain is not defined by a parameter the concurrent manager uses the value defined for the profile option Concurrent:Conflicts Domain. Lastly, if the domain is not provided by a program parameter and the Concurrent:Conflicts Domain profile option has not been defined the 'Standard' domain is used. The Standard domain is the default for all requests.

All programs use the Standard conflict domain unless a value is defined for the profile option Concurrent:Conflicts Domain or a conflict domain is defined through a program parameter.

You can refer the following links for further details.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/fnd/incomp01.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/fnd/incomp02.htm

Regards,

Sivabalanarayanan L